# truncating a system and plotting it on bode

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Let system G(s) be:
$$ G(s)=\sum_{i=0}^{10}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)^2}\frac{\omega_i}{s^2+2\zeta_i \omega_i s+\omega_i ^2}$$
$$\omega_i=\frac{(2i+1)\pi}{T}\, T=1\, \zeta_i=0.2$$
Its impulse response is an approximation (truncated Fourier series) of a slowly decaying triangular wave. Using the balanced truncation method, find an r-order approximation Gr(s) of G(s) such that the following
error bound, is guaranteed:
$$\lVert G-G_r\rVert_\infty<0.1\lVert G\rVert_H$$
and plot the bode plots (using matlab) of G and Gr and their impulse response on the time interval [0,5]

so far, i've managed to find the Hankel singular values of the system and also $\lVert G\rVert_H$ by using the matlab command of balreal(G) but i'm having an issue with turnicating the system to guarantee the demand of $\lVert G-G_r\rVert_\infty<0.1\lVert G\rVert_H$

thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Although I am familiar with Matlab, but not with its Signal Processing, Control etc. toolboxes, mentionning "balreal" function doesn't ring anything for me. The least you can do is say what this function is supposed to do. But dsp site (digital signal processing) https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate spot for your question.